# Pass a multi value argument to a panel view

Tags: views, panels

Is there a way to pass a multi value argument from panels to a panel view?

I have a node with an entity relation field on it and load this node as context in page manager.

I have also a view which accepts a multi value argument (contextual filter). Not multiple arguments I mean an argument where you have multiple nids normally separated by comma if you would enter them in the url.

I want to pass the nids from the entity relation field on the node loaded as context to the view I load in a panel on the same page.

Maybe it is more understandable by describing it step by step.

- I created a page manager page with a path /admin/something/!nid
- The node identified by !nid is loaded as a context so I have all the
  field values on the node.
- The node has a field that stores a small amount of other nodes as references.
- I want to pass the nids of the referenced nodes to a panel view as argument number one.
- I have done this with one nid but have no idea how to do it with multiple ones.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The entity context provided by CTools [uses tokens](http://drupalcode.org/project/ctools.git/blob/10a2674c4cd0c3344c2ae9616c81bf7995dcdd36:/plugins/contexts/entity.inc#l216) to provide keywords for the given context.

So if you implement your own token which uses a node object as data source it will end up among your node context keywords, and you can pass it to the view as an argument.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7538759) to get an idea how to implement tokens.

Your token replacement method should extract the referenced node IDs from the loaded node, and concatenate '+' or ',' between them (it depends on how your argument is configured in the view).